# How to implement the Cmake -C option with the conan Cmake helper

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

Right now I use cmake like this:

```
cmake .. -C pathToMyFile
```

I would like to configure cmake with the Conan Cmake helper so that in my `conanfile.py` I would have

```py
cmake=CMake(self)
cmake.configure()
```

How can I still tell Cmake to Pre-load my script to populate the cache. I tried

```py
cmake.configure(args="-C mypath")
```

but that did not work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need it? CMake helper uses its own cache, you don't need to configure anything extra. Besides that, you can re-use the same CMake object, to avoid calling twice.

The correct flow is:

```py
def _configure_cmake(self):
   if self._cmake:
       return self._cmake
   self._cmake = CMake(self)
   self._cmake.definitions["BUILD_TESTING"] = False
   self._cmake.configure() # it runs cmake <build_folder> -DBUILD_TESTING=False ...
   return self._cmake

def build(self):
   cmake = self._configure_cmake()
   cmake.build() # it runs cmake --build .

def package(self):
   cmake = self._configure_cmake()
   cmake.install()  # it runs cmake --build . --target install
```

Also, CMake `args` is not a string, but a list, it's well [documented](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/build_helpers/cmake.html#configure), thus, you have to pass:

```
cmake.configure(args=["-C", "mypath"])
```